# clipping mask causing problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Whenever  i clipping mask any image it takes extra invisible space...
And it causes problem when i mock it.
Is there any way to get rid of that extra space in bounding box?
I want image 1 to get the same bounding box like image 2.
[image: TO]

Comment: While not *technically* a duplicate as you've worded it.... what you need to do is crop the image not mask it. Clipping Masks **always** honor the raster image dimensions for the bounding box. Cropping the raster image will cause the bounding box to be relative to the crop dimensions.. thus the duplicate link on how to crop.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Scott i have one question. what if i draw a custom shape and want an image to fit in that exact shape? no way tht extra invisible space is leaving the scene. so far i have read your refereed answer and still tht invisible space is keep occurring...

Comment: **All raster images are rectangular**. Its the nature of raster images. Therefore you **must** mask if you want a non-rectangular shape.. in which case, the image's native rectangle **will** be still there under the mask. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: oh no :( ... Thank you :(

Comment: @Scott Am really sorry for asking you this.. i dnt know who to ask. my apology. I dnt understand why i can't ask anything.. previously i write my queries and publish it. but now there is no publish option but 'review your question'!!   and the interface has changed. it is saying 'ask a public question' what is happening? am i not allowed to ask anything anymore?  am really sorry if i have disturbed you. :(

Comment: @suraiyaabedin [Please come to our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot), we can try to see what's going on

Comment: okay. Thank you.